# Initializing multiple variable in one statement causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to nest a list of objects in a list; I have tried the following:

Instantiation:

```
  public static List<PhonePeople> Helpdesk, Admins = new List<PhonePeople>();
  public static List<List<PhonePeople>> PDepartments = 
          new List<List<PhonePeople>>{Helpdesk,Admins};
```

Attempting to add to the helpdesk list as follows:

```
 MainWindow.PDepartments[counter].Add(thisPerson);
```

Error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I defined counter to 0 , 0 is the index for helpdesk. Mainwindow is where the static list resides.
I believe there is an issue with my List of list's or the way i am adding to it;

whats wrong?

Comment: Note that I think it is not direct duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) as it more about declaring multiple variables in single statement. @Mods, consider reading the linked question to help you with debugging this type f exception (now and later).

Comment: Thanks Alexei; Will do this next time, I skimmed the titles but was close minded on "nested lists" instead of all the information involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line `public static List<PhonePeople> Helpdesk, Admins = new List<PhonePeople>();` is only instantiating `Admins` not `HelpDesk`

Comment: Exactly what I was just about to write :-)

Comment: Oh! how do you chain these? helpdesk = admins = new list<phonepeople>  ?  
Thanks by the way this has been a problem for a while!

Comment: No, that would point the variables to the same object, you need a separate instance for each object reference, so you need two `new` statements.